# Can Visual Studio designer files be edited outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, winforms, mono

Visual Studio creates designer files (such as frmMain.Designer.cs) for WinForms forms. In these files, there is a method called "InitializeComponent", and it has a comment: do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.

Now I want to know: Can these files be edited outside of Visual Studio? Is there any mystery in these files?

I am trying to port WinForms projects to Linux, using Mono. To maintain these projects, I want to use a WinForms designer. Visual Studio does not run on Linux, so I can only use some other tool. For example, the web page "https://www.mono-project.com/archived/winforms_designer/" talks about an unfinished designer. Maybe this designer can be finished with some efforts. Obviously, such a tool needs to edit these designer files. So, I want to know: Can these files be edited outside of Visual Studio? Is there any mystery in these files?

Comment: The designer files are just text. There's no mistery. What's in `InitializeComponent()` is used by the VS designers to generate the graphic interface. The *warning* (info) is based on the fact that when you change something in the visual designer, what's in that method is overwritten. But of course you can - and sometimes need tro - edit it. Just remember that anything not related to the visual presentation is deleted when any changes are made in the VS Form Designer

Comment: When you open the designer, Visual Studio interprets the code in *.Designer.cs to create the visual designer UI. But it's understanding of the code is limited. I.e., it will not understand control structures like loops. But you can add new controls, or replace one type of control by another, etc.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes actually I’m pretty sure it just executes whatever arbitrary code is in that file - loops included. I remember playing around with it once just to see how far I could push it. I had a button cycling through background colours in the designer all by itself, I even got the designer code to write to a file if I remember correctly. But maybe they’ve tightened it up since then? I kind of hope so..

Comment: Yes the loops runs when the application is running, but at design time the Visual Studio designer does not understand it. E.g. If you create and add 10 TextBoxes in a loop in `InitializeComponent` and open the form in the designer, you will not see these TextBoxes. Then, when you make changes in the designer and save, the loop is gone, because the designer only saves the controls visible in the designer UI.

Comment: 1) There are three VS WinForms designers (legacy .NET Framework one, legacy .NET Core one, and the latest .NET Core one based on Roslyn). They each allow some manual modification, but due to the never disclosed implementation details your edits can completely corrupt the whole file. That's why Microsoft wanted you not to manually edit the file. 2) Mono or Mono WinForms are going away in months, no matter how much you like to go that way. If you don't plan to take over all the responsibilities to support yourself, stop now and don't waste your time.

Comment: @LexLi Is there another (not Mono) way to port a .NET WinForms project to Linux, without complete rewriting of the project?

Comment: There isn't a way for WinForms. Microsoft stopped major development on WinForms a long while ago, and revived it on Windows only after .NET Core 3.0. Mono WinForms was the focus before 2008, but later the efforts moved to mobile/games. So if you are working on a WinForms project today, the only supported platform is Windows. To go cross platform you must choose another UI framework, https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Answer (score -1):

You can edit these files; there’s no mystery to them. In fact you can probably even do it inside of Visual Studio.

The reason you *shouldn’t* edit these files is that they are auto-generated by your IDE, so when you edit them, you risk:

- Losing your changes as soon as you make a change in the IDE’s designer window (causing the IDE to regenerate the file)
- Causing the designer window to stop working (for example if you add code that causes an exception).

Sometimes, editing the designer file can be helpful. For example if you have a lot of controls to add, you can add them more efficiently by copying and pasting code and editing some positioning values rather than using the designer, which can be slower.

In this case, you wouldn’t lose your changes because the changes will be reflected in the IDE designer window. Anything you see in that window will be written back to the designer file whenever the IDE saves that file.

Comment: WinForms designers (three of them) are not open sourced, and a lot of mysteries are there around them. The old CodeDOM based designers are highly sensitive to manual edits, so this answer puts readers in risks (like losing everything in the designer.cs file).